# How to accept only some change sets in rtc source control

Tags: version-control, eclipse-plugin, rtc

I am using eclipse plugin for RTC. Not able to find a option to accept only some of the change sets and not all of them at one time.

Is there an option for this?

[image: previously i.stack.imgur.com/daLHa.png]

Answer (score 1):

You should see in the "Pending Changes view" some work items or baselines in the "Incoming" section that you can unfold.
Once unfolded, you see a list of change sets: right click on one (or several selected together) and you can accept only those.

[image: select change set]

But if the change set depends on a previous one, RTC will will first propose to apply that change set as a patch.

[image: patch]

> The repository workspace you are accepting this change set into doesn't have all the change sets that led up to this change set.
>   You can try applying the contents of the change set as a patch or you could try and accept more change sets together.
>
> Do you want to apply the change set as a patch?
>
> Learn about patches and content accept:
>
> You are accepting a change set that depends on change sets that are not already in your workspace. This would create a gap in the component's change history.
>   You can resolve this problem by accepting the changes as a patch.

So here: click cancel and widen your change sets selection.

Comment: I am not even able to right click on the change sets! Anything in the plugin which needs to be enabled first?

Comment: @Ankit can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Screenshot added. I am not able to right click on the change sets.

Comment: @Ankit I have added a screenshot as well. Check your role associated to your profile in the project area.

Comment: There is an option to accept all incoming baseline and change sets and i am currently using that to accept change sets. Could it be a role issue still? What is the version or RTC plugin that you are using?

Comment: The version I use is 4.0.3

Comment: I see one of the change set has a conflict (concurrent modifications both outgoing and incoming on the same file(s)) Maybe you need to accept that change set first and resolve the conflict?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68858/discussion-between-ankit-and-vonc).